# Regular Expression to replace HTML tags

Tags: c#, regex

I'm newer to regular expressions and am trying to write a regular expression which will find all `<p>` and `</p>` tags in a string and replace them with `<span>` and `</span>` respectively.  I've come up with this:

```
Regex rex = new Regex("<(p|P) />", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
            storeHours = rex.Replace(storeHours, "<span />");
```

I also tried just chaining 2 string replaces which didn't work either.

```
 storeHours = storeHours.Replace("<p>", "<span>").Replace("</p>", "</span>");
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Why don't you use string.replace("<p>"."<span>")

Comment: @user3267755 What do you mean `String.Replace` "didn't work"?

Comment: The `Replace` method should work just fine for your purpose here - what was the result after you tried it?

Comment: It's odd that the `Replace` method isn't working.  Possibly because I'm in a razor view?  This is a field that I'm pulling from our Umbraco CMS as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code

```
storeHours = storeHours.Replace("<p>", "<span>").Replace("</p>", "</span>");
```

works fine. I suppose that your problem can be with encodings. What is code of your client?

Comment: This solved my issue for the `Replace`.  I changed my code to be  
`var encoded = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(storeHours);`
            `storeHours = encoded.Replace("<p>", "<span>").Replace("</p>", "</span>");`
 and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use Regex for HTML operations. You should use HTML parser, you can try with HTML Agility Pack. Here is an example:

```
public string ReplacePElement(string htmlContent) 
{
  HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
  doc.LoadHtml(htmlContent);

  foreach(HtmlNode p in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("p"))
  {
    string value = tb.InnerText.Length>0 ? tb.InnerText : "&nbsp;";
    HtmlNode lbl = doc.CreateElement("span");
    lbl.InnerHtml = value;

    tb.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(lbl, tb);
  }

  return doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have some attributes (e.g. `style`) then the following regexp works better:

```js
storeHours.replace(/<p\b/gmi, "<span");
```

(It replaces open and close tags, too.)